# How to get Azure bindings to FastAPI endpoint

Tags: python, azure-functions, fastapi, azure-durable-functions, fastapi-middleware

How to pass a string `starter` from Azure http_trigger to the FastAPI endpoint?

Currently I'm hacking this by setting `starter` in `context.trace_context.attributes`

Or alternative to get the Azure bindings into FastAPI?

```py
# "Client side"
def get_client(request: Request) -> df.DurableOrchestrationClient:
    starter = request.scope["azure_functions.trace_context"].attributes["starter"]
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    return client

# This is the FastAPI version of the `route="startOrchestrator"`
# `async def start_orchestrator(req: func.HttpRequest, client):`
@fastapi_app.get(path="/fast_orchestrator")
async def fast_orchestrator(
    client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient = Depends(get_client)
):
    instance_id = await client.start_new("my_orchestrator")

    reply = f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'."
    logging.info(reply)
    # Don't know how to convert this back to Azure func.HttpRequest
    # return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

    # Here we should build the HTTP 202 with location header to the /status/{instance_id}

    return reply

# Sort of "middleware" side
@df_app.route(route="{*route}", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@df_app.generic_input_binding(arg_name="starter", type="durableClient")
async def http_trigger(
    req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context, starter: str
) -> func.HttpResponse:
    context.trace_context.attributes["starter"] = starter
    response: func.HttpResponse = await func.AsgiMiddleware(fastapi_app).handle_async(
        req, context
    )
    # Do activity or orchestration based on response
    return response
```

Comment: You could pass starter as a query parameter

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin then all the requests will have that query parameter, I don't see how that is much better than using the context.trace_context.

Comment: Do you want to use `context.trace_context.attributes`? Are you getting any error while running the given code?

Comment: No error, code works fine but both passing a query parameter or adding the context.trace_context seems to all requests is not simple nor elegant. Ideally I would like to remove the `async def http_trigger` and just use FastAPI endpoints.

Comment: Can you specify your requirement? If you will remove http_trigger then how are you going to pass data from http_trigger to fast API?

Comment: That is my requirement to remove the `http_trigger`, just like the original code from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/blob/main/function_app.py only has 
`app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fastapi_app, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)` I would like to go back to that way and still access the `starter` or `generic_input_binding` from FastAPI using only the `func.AsgiFunctionApp`.


Similar problem has been raised here by other user
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python/issues/461

Comment: have you tried the solution provided here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python/issues/461#issuecomment-1846752912, I believe it fits with your requirement?

Comment: That solution was added by me, so yes I've tried it :)